# OpenCL group size meaning

Tags: opencl

What does the local group size mean for OpenCL? If the work groupsize is 1, does it mean that only one thread is running at the same time?

I found we can set NULL to `cl_ndrange` to let the program automatically select the group size, how can we know what group size is selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In opencl kernel,

```
get_local_size (0);
```

gives you "8" for a 8x16 work-group-sized kernel while

```
get_local_size (1);
```

gives "16" for the same kernel execution. If it is 3D kernel, then "2" as a parameter gives the third dimension's size. To query number of dimensions(1,2,3 ?),

```
 get_work_dim ();
```

is used.

Local work group size gives number of threads per hardware synchronization. For AMD gpus its 256 maximum while Nvidia and cpus can go 1024. When you give "1" as this work group size, only single thread per synchronizating compute unit is obtained(if not restricted by a min-value from drivers or hardware) and maximum local memory per thread(also per wave) is achieved.

At the same time? Whole execution is folded onto a handful number of compute units, letting multiple issued execution and increasing occupation, especially workgroup size is small and local memory is enough. if L=1 lets MAX_VALUE waves fold onto same compute unit, L=64 lets only 16 waves to fold, L=256 lets only 4 waves fold onto, for example. Yes, at the same time but not at the same synchronization scope.

Some vendors' some models can do concurrent kernel executions to fully occupy pipelines so that single thread may not be alone but with another thread from another kernel of another commandqueue.

For example, the upcoming r9 390x gpu will have 64 compute units each having maybe 4 vector units each having 16 arithmetics&fpu units totaling 4096 cores. AMD's compute unit has 64 cores total, a core is being streamed by around 4 several waves so having 256 threads per compute unit. But this threading system could be different than those on CPUs so context swithcing maybe faster and cache contention is minimum because of switching in groups.

Comment: But how can a group size be more than hundred? Doesn't the GPU only own 32 cores?

Comment: they are compute units each having many vector units or scalar units.

Comment: If I double the group size, is it likely that the runtime will be reduced to half?

Comment: The work group size indicates how many "work-items" will run fully parallel (with syncs, barriers and local mem available). And is hardware dependent, if you double it, and the HW can't you will get an error.

Comment: sometimes faster, sometimes slower, sometimes fails(as DarkZeros said).

Comment: @DarkZeros "The work group size indicates how many "work-items" will run fully parallel". No, it doesn't. It indicates how many work-items will be able to synchronize on barriers, and thus how many must, at a minimum, be concurrent on a given compute unit if barrier synchronization is used. On real systems only subsets of those work-items are likely to actually run in parallel, and it is possible that multiple work-groups will be concurrent hence it is a minimum. It is resource limited, but not directly hardware dependent.